# Problem with Silverlight and MEF

Tags: silverlight, mef

I've refferenced my project to the MEF's dlls
System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.dll

from C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client

But the compiler doesn't recognize the PartInitializer.
Why ?!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PartInitializer` is changed to `CompositionInitializer`:

```
 CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this)
```

Comment: I was doing a project yesterday using SL and MEF :o)

Comment: Ofcourse, I wanted to do that before but StackOverflow didn't let me before 9 minutes been past after asking the question.